# angular2 set up issues

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

```
$ npm install
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\angular2-seed\package.json'
npm WARN angular2-seed No description
npm WARN angular2-seed No repository field.
npm WARN angular2-seed No README data
npm WARN angular2-seed No license field.
```

---

```
$ npm bugs
npm ERR! path cmd
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn cmd
npm ERR! enoent spawn cmd ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\christiansimonet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-05-30T19_45_53_640Z-debug.log
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You have to add `package.json` in your angular2 application. For simple steps visit https://angular.io. And this is not the correct way to ask. Please visit the link @EmrePiskin has shared and update your question.